# best source revision control software on MacOS

Tags: macos, controls, revision

On MacOS, I am coding in ObjectiveC and Java. I want to have a revision software runs locally on my machine, good GUI, excellent tooling in terms of easy check in, check out, diff, history etc. Free would be a bonus too! :) What's the best/popular ones out there that can serve the basic needs above? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popular DVCSes, which fit your locally-running requirement, are Git, Bazaar, Mercurial (Hg), and others that people will be happy to point out, I'm sure.

Git seems to have the best-looking gui options, some which are reviewed here: http://fuelyourcoding.com/rise-of-the-mac-git-guis/

Comment: As an aside, I've tried to use a GUI with most VCS systems and never maintained it.  Command line just becomes faster for everyday use.

Comment: That's not true when you're trying to pick portions of files to commit or need to view a complicated history with lots of merges in it.  That's pretty much all GitX does, and I can't see a command-line utility doing either as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try Git with [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Subversion I think that [Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/index.php) is unbeatable in OSX (is not free but is worth paying for it)